# MKPointAnnotation not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkannotation

Hello i got this method:

```
-(void)adresseZeigen
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    selectedAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];

    selectedAnnotation.title = selectedCompanyName;
    selectedAnnotation.subtitle = selectedCompanyAdresse;
    selectedAnnotation.coordinate = selectedCompanyPoint;


    NSLog(@"selected title: %@",selectedAnnotation.title);
    NSLog(@"selected subtitle: %@",selectedAnnotation.subtitle);
    NSLog(@"selected latitude is: %f", self.selectedAnnotation.coordinate.latitude );
    NSLog(@"selected longitude is: %f", self.selectedAnnotation.coordinate.longitude );

    [mapView addAnnotation:selectedAnnotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion selectedRegion;

    selectedRegion.center = selectedCompanyPoint;
    selectedRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
    selectedRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    [mapView setRegion:selectedRegion animated:YES];

}
```

it should actually give me a annotation in my mapview.

My Log output is:

```
-[SecondViewController adresseZeigen]
selected title: Company 2
selected subtitle: Company 2 Adresse
selected latitude is: 48.620000
selected longitude is: 9.460000
```

but somehow I dont get a annotation on map.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you checked that mapView is a valid reference when you try to use it?

Comment: any other opinions? well i think it has something to do with my segue. i have a segue to a tableView. with did select row, i delegate a method in my viewController and dismiss my tableView. this method calls this adresseZeigen-method

Comment: Are these segues modal? And do you call this adresseZeigen method when the controller with the mapView is not on screen?

Comment: i found the solution. as expected it had to do with my delegation. i set the delegation in my tableview. now i set it with preparefor segue in my secondview. and now it works

Answer (score 0):

This alone is not gonna give you any actual annotation views on the map. In order to have annotation views in your map, you need to declare the MKMapViewDelegate for your view controller, declare it as your mapview delegate and implement the method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

This is the method that actually produces the annotation view for the map view. In your case you might want to use an `MKPinAnnotationView` for your MKPointAnnotation!

You can check the protocol reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html).

EDIT: An example implementation of the method (that assumes that all of your MKPointAnnotations have the same purpose) could be:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"MyReuseID";
    MKPinAnnotationView * view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (!view) {
        view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        //custom setup of your view, such as
        //view.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. I will try it. What i yesterday tried made me more cunfused:

i copied the content of "-(void)adresseZeigen" in "-(void) viewDidLoad" and i got a annotation after loading view.

Comment: It is not necessary to implement viewForAnnotation to display default annotations.  When not implemented, the map will display standard red pins.  Verify that mapView is not nil as @Wain commented -- that's one possibility.

Comment: you are right. with `if (!mapView) NSLog(@"bing");` i get the logoutput "bing". So mapView seems to be nil.
i am somehow stuck. can someone please tell me how to change this?

Comment: Is mapView an outlet that you get from the storyboard? If it is, is it properly connected to the map view object in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes it is an outlet:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;`

Comment: If a map is showing on screen, it means that your IBOutlet is not connected properly to the map view object in the storyboard! Right click on the map view object in the storyboard and check that, in the popup window, your View Controller is listed under Referencing Outlets

Comment: Reference Outlets of my Map View:
mapView -> Second View Controller - Map

seems to be allright